# Resources Exceeded in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I keeping getting resources exceeded for the following query. I've tried running in batch mode and from the command line and nothing seems to be working. Anyone have ideas?

`SELECT num, extid, amount, note, balance
FROM
  (
  SELECT row_number() over(partition by extid order by stamp) as num
    , extid, stamp, ds, amount, note, balance
  FROM monte.ledger2_trailing_21d 
  WHERE ds >= '2015-02-09'
  ORDER BY extid, stamp
  )
WHERE num <= 10
limit 300`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a deceptively expensive query; timeseries analysis is always hard in SQL-like environments. The `PARTITION BY` clause you have written requires all of the data for a single *extid* to be present in memory on a single machine, which is overloading it and causing your resources exceeded error.

You can mitigate this RAM requirement by having a `ROWS` clause to limit the scope of your partition. Here is an example:

```
SELECT extid, stamp, ds, amount, note, balance
FROM (
  SELECT
    extid, stamp, ds, amount, note, balance,
    MAX(tenth_stamp) OVER(PARTITION BY extid) AS target_stamp
  FROM (
    SELECT extid, stamp, ds, amount, note, balance,
      MIN(stamp) OVER (
        PARTITION BY extid
        ORDER BY stamp DESC
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 9 FOLLOWING
      ) AS tenth_stamp
    FROM
      [monte.ledger2_trailing_21d]
    WHERE ds >= '2015-02-09'
  )
)
WHERE stamp >= target_stamp
ORDER BY extid, stamp
LIMIT 300
```

The inner-most sub-select extracts your data and a field `tenth_stamp` that holds the least stamp of the 10 rows examined. Using `MIN()` makes this work even when there are fewer than 10 rows for any given `extid`.

The middle sub-select finds the largest `tenth_stamp` for each `extid`. This is the tenth total stamp for that `extid`. The outer SELECT can then restrict the result to only rows with a `stamp` within the ten most recent `stamp` for their respective `extid`, giving you the desired result.

When executed, this takes a total of 4 stages. It will not run fast, but never requires large amounts of data in a single location. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Rows clause. I still needed to do row_number in an outer query in order to analyze the order in which users interact with events, but it runs without a problem now. In addition, could you please edit out my account info from your answer. I'd prefer to not have the full file path listed in a public forum.

Comment: FYI Matthew is a BigQuery engineer with access to the query logs, in case you were wondering how he found your project ID (and inadvertently added it to the response).